# Perl hangs when pushing onto array

Tags: perl

I'm running the following code to extract a list of IDs from a mysql database and store them in an array. I'm doing this exact sequence of steps in other places in my code, but in this location, something funny happens and Perl just hangs and never returns. Every where else in the code, it works fine. If I run this code as is, it runs fine, but if I uncomment the push() function, it hangs. Is this a bug?

```
my $result = $db->query($sqlstring)
if ($result->numrows > 0) {
    my @list = ();
    while (my %row = $result->fetchhash) {
        my $studyid = $row{'study_id'} + 0;
        print "$studyid\n";
        WriteLog("Found study [" . $studyid . "]");
        #push(@list,$studyid); # uncomment this to hang it
    }
    return \@list;
}
```

EDIT: I tried the data::dumper. But now the freezing occurs in a new location. In the code below, it freezes right after the very last Dumper(@list) statement. (I also switched to DBI from MySQL module, but that had no effect).

```
my @list = ();
my $result = $dbh->prepare($sqlstring);
$result->execute();
WriteLog($sqlstring);
if ($result->rows > 0) {
    while (my $row = $result->fetchrow_hashref()) {
        my $studyid = $row->{study_id};
        WriteLog("Found study [" . $studyid . "]");
        push @list,$studyid;
    }

}

print Dumper(@list);

return \@list;
```

Comment: What module (including version) are you using that provides `fetchhash` on a result object?

Comment: Good question, its "MySQL". How would I find out the version? I'm using Perl 5.10.1 on CentOS 6, 64-bit.

Comment: It is unlikely that the `push` function is causing an infinite loop here. More likely, the code that calls this subroutine that causes it.

Comment: Not sure its an infinite loop outside of the function. It prints the list of IDs to the screen once, and then hangs there. It prints the same thing to a file, so its not printing the same list of IDs multiple times.

Comment: @GregB Let me rephrase that. The code you have provided does not make it possible to solve the problem you have described. Your question will likely remain unanswered unless you provide more code. Try creating a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) where the small code you provide can be run to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @GregB, I meant the Perl module. Or are you saying that you're using the DBD:mysql driver with DBI?

Comment: @GregB, Are you saying the program hangs, or the `push` does? If it's the former, find out call is actually hanging. If it's the latter, I don't believe you, so you'll have to convince me with more information.

Comment: @GregB NO! use Dumper inside the loop! See if that `push` is working. The question is where you're getting stuck. Is `$result->fetchrow_hashref()` hanging? Is it returning anything in `%row`? Is it the `push` itself?

Comment: @GregB How do you know where the program is freezing? It looks like you're saying the loop is successful with the `push`, but the Dumper is out of the while loop.

Comment: @DavidW. I did try the data dumper inside the loop. Indeed the `push` is working since the array fills up and `$result->fetchrow_hashref()` works correctly too. With the latest code, the array fills up correctly, but now it hangs before (or maybe during) the `return \@list`

Comment: Can you show what happens after `return \@list;`? I'm guess that you do something with that list and the problem is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When is this freezing? Is it freezing on the first call to `push`, or on some subsequent call?
- Are you sure you're pushing what you think you're pushing?

What you should do is to `use Data::Dumper;` and then do a `dumper` before the `push`.

```
use Data::Dumper;
use feature qw(say);

my $result = $db->query($sqlstring)
if ( $result->numrows > 0 ) {
    my @list;
    while ( my %row = $result->fetchhash ) {
        my $studyid = $row{study_id} + 0;
        say $studyid;
        WriteLog("Found study [" . $studyid . "]");
        say "List: " . Dumper @list;
        say "Study ID: " . Dumper \$studyid;
        push @list, $studyid;     # uncomment this to hang it
    }
    return \@list;
}
```

Note I'm using `say` instead of `print`. `Dumper` can cause problems if you don't parenthesize it and use `print`. If you don't want to use `say`, then you'll need to do this:

```
print "Study ID: " . Dumper ( \$studyid ) . "\n";
```

By the way, what do you return if there are no rows?

Comment: What are these mysterious `print` problems you speak of? There is no difference between using `say` and using `print` besides the newline added by `say`. Also, you made a reference of the scalar `\$studyid` when you should have done that with the array `\@list` instead.

Comment: If you say `print Dumper $foo . "\n";` , you'll get something like `$VAR1 = 'Foo::Bar=HASH(0x7f84490070d0)'` instead of a data dump. You need to say `print Dumper ( $foo ) . "\n";`.

Comment: So... this is weird. It turns out the problem was even farther along in the code. Using `exit(0)`, I was able to determine that it was stuck inside a while loop later in the code. The problem is that Perl didn't print anything to the screen prior to that while statement, so I assumed it was hanging at that `push` statement... even though there were several print statements between the `push` and `while`. The data dumper started me down that path. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Should have told you to add `$| = 1;` to the top of your program. This turns on [auto flush](http://searchco.de/?q=%24%7C%20Perl) and would have caused your print statements to print out immediately instead of buffering.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to mention that we just had this same problem with one of our scripts.  The script is being run through Jenkins and the problem was that there wasn't really a problem.  We just hadn't seen all of the output up to the point of the program's current state.  So it ***looked*** like it was hung on a push - it was actually hung legitimately on a sleep() call a few lines later.  It was fixed with the auto-flush flag which David W. mentioned.  The problem was worsened by the use of Jenkins as an execution environment (vs the command-line debugger).  The STDOUT/STDIN pipe opened in the Jenkins context doesn't exist in a command-line shell.  So we would never see the issue from the command line - further confusing us.  Once I realized that there was a communications pipe involved then things fell into place.